# Can the power series for $e^{-|t|}$ be uniformly bounded for $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $f(t) = e^{-|t|}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The function $f$ has the everywhere convergent power series expansion

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|t|^n}{n!}.$$

> I would like to know whether there exists some $C > 0$ independent of $t$ so that for all integers $M \ge 0$, 
>   $$\Big|\sum_{n=0}^M \frac{(-1)^n|t|^n}{n!} \Big| \le C.$$

If we were to instead consider the power series expansion, for, say, $e^t$, then we do not expect there to be a uniform constant, because $e^t$ becomes too large as $t \to \infty$. However, since $f$ is decaying at both $\pm \infty$, I suspect such a $C$ can be found, and one will need to rely somehow on the cancellation of the positive and negative terms in the series.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Even for some fixed (nonzero) M, do you think there exists many polynomials that are bounded on the whole real line?

Comment: How about $C=1$? Isn't it true that $$\Big|\sum_{n=0}^M \frac{(-1)^n|t|^n}{n!} \Big| \leq \sum_{n=0}^M \Big|\frac{(-1)^n|t|^n}{n!}\Big|$$

$$= \sum_{n=0}^M \frac{|t|^n}{n!}$$
$$\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{|t|^n}{n!}$$
$$=e^{-|t|}$$
$$\leq1$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: @MPW Yes - the sum you wrote down is $e^{|t|}$, not $e^{-|t|}$.

Comment: Ah, indeed, my bad.

Comment: That is not a power series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

For any $M>0$ the term 
$\sum_{n=0}^M \frac{(-1)^n|t|^n}{n!}$ is a polynomial in $|t|$ which is unbounded as $|t| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that by letting $t=M\in\mathbb{N}^+$, we have that
$$\lim_{M\to +\infty}\Big|\sum_{n=0}^M \frac{(-1)^n M^n}{n!} \Big|=+\infty$$